# How to create a dynamic group in AAD using AAD Graph

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I am able to create a group using ActiveDirectoryClient:

```
await activeDirectoryClient.Groups.AddGroupAsync(new Group() {
    DisplayName = "Group4",
    MailNickname = "test",
    MailEnabled = false,
    SecurityEnabled = true
});
```

However, this Group model doesn't provide property which specifies the group type and dynamic group rule.
I also find a way to make an API call which can have the group type figured in the body, but this example doesn't show how to specify the dynamic group rule:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0

I would like to know how to do it with C# code implementing the same logic with Azure Portal Ibiza
[Azure Portal UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oacol.png)

I used the F12 dev tool to view the api call used by Azure Portal, https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/groups/
and the request body is like [Screen shot of request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhFPk.png)

Answer (score 2):

After investigation, I find that MS Graph's Group Model provide the property related with dynamic group staff and could implement my purpose there, so I will go with MS Graph instead of AAD Graph.